# Workbox : get event when files are in cache

Tags: angular, service-worker, workbox

I use workbox to generate service-worker in my project.
Workbox doc : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox

My app is supposed to be 100% offline, so i have to put all files in cache during the first launch. And i'm looking for a way to display a message to user to say that app is loaded, offline is ready.

Is there a way to know when all files are in cache and to listen to an event that say "all files are cached, let's go" or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor progress of precaching using a custom plugin

```
const myPlugin = {
    cacheDidUpdate: async ({request, response, event}) => {
      // track progress of all precaching and communicate to the page using postMessage or BroadcastChannel
      return response;
    }
}

workbox.precaching.addPlugins([myPlugin]);
```

Once all precaching is done, you can show a message to the user.

Here is one way to do it:

https://progressify.org/track-and-display-precaching-progress-in-a-pwa-with-workbox-and-broadcastchannel-api/

Comment: Is there a way to pass a count of cached files to the client? I tried using localStorage, but can't use it apparently

Comment: Also, you have a mirror of the link? It's broken now